# How to play embedded video in WP7 - Phonegap?

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, cordova, html5-video

I need to play an embedded video file in my WP7 phonegap application. The file (dizzy.mp4) is located in the www folder along with the following layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>PhoneGap WP7</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <video onclick="play()">
        <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <video onclick="play()">
        <source src="./dizzy.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

If the first video element is clicked, the video file is being downloaded from the Internet and all is ok. But after clicking on the second (local video) just a video player screen with 'Opening...' label appears. Both videos are the same video file.

The app was run both on an emulator and on a real device (Nokia Lumnia 710 with WF7.5 Mango), the result is the same.

I tried to set different build actions to the video file: Content, Resource, Embedded Resource. It doesn't help.

How to make it work?

**UPDATE:** A similar issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477582/wp7-player-freezes-if-html5-video-and-isolated-storage). Is it a WP7 bug?

Comment: 100% not a WP7 bug. Its a Phonegap or even HTML5 bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround. The following code is a Phonegap command that implements video play back functionality.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using WP7GapClassLib.PhoneGap;
using WP7GapClassLib.PhoneGap.Commands;
using WP7GapClassLib.PhoneGap.JSON;

namespace PhoneGap.Extension.Commands
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Implements video play back functionality.
    /// </summary>
    public class Video : BaseCommand
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Video player object
        /// </summary>
        private MediaElement _player;

        [DataContract]
        public class VideoOptions
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Path to video file
            /// </summary>
            [DataMember(Name = "src")]
            public string Src { get; set; }
        }

        public void Play(string args)
        {
            VideoOptions options = JsonHelper.Deserialize<VideoOptions>(args);

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    _Play(options.Src);

                    DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, e.Message));
                }
            }); 
        }

        private void _Play(string filePath)
        {
            // this.player is a MediaElement, it must be added to the visual tree in order to play
            PhoneApplicationFrame frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
            if (frame != null)
            {
                PhoneApplicationPage page = frame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
                if (page != null)
                {
                    Grid grid = page.FindName("LayoutRoot") as Grid;
                    if (grid != null && _player == null)
                    {
                        _player = new MediaElement();
                        grid.Children.Add(this._player);
                        _player.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                }
            }

            Uri uri = new Uri(filePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            if (uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
            {
                _player.Source = uri;
            }
            else
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (isoFile.FileExists(filePath))
                    {
                        using (
                            IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open,
                                                                                             isoFile))
                        {
                            _player.SetSource(stream);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Source doesn't exist");
                    }
                }
            }

            _player.Play();
        }
    }

}
```

There is only the Play function here, but it can be extended to support Stop/Pause/Close ect.

To register this command on client side:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function playVideo(src) {

        PhoneGap.exec(         //PhoneGap.exec = function(success, fail, service, action, args)
            null, //success
            null, //fail
            "Video", //service
            "Play", //action
            {src: src} //args
           ); 
    };
   </script>
```

To play back the file:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" onClick="playVideo('/app/www/dizzy.mp4');">Play</a>
```

Pay attention to the path '/app/www/dizzy.mp4'.

Comment: Hey Andrei Schneider, I have got a question to your workaround. Where do you save the videos ? Do you copy them into the isolated Storage? Or are the videos in the www folder of your app? And how exactly do you implement your plugin to the project? I have got videos saved in the application and use your code but when calling the phonegap.exec(...) the code fails. It would be awesome if you can answer the questions! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hey  DrLudwig3, Look at the GapSourceDictionary.xml file in your Phonegap project. It contains a list of files. There is a  GapBrowser_Loaded method in the PGView class. Inside this method GapSourceDictionary.xml is loaded, parsed. And the files are loaded into Isolated storage.

Comment: If you want, leave me your email. I will send you the source code of my test project for the next 12 hours.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented the functions of play music on Android platform with PhoneGap, and my code snapshot as below:
HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('/android_asset/www/music/noya_wyt.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
```

JavaScript code:

```
 function playAudio(src) {
        // Create Media object from src
        my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();
 }
```

And I think you can change your video "src" path, and try again. If the app still doesn't work, you can try to call the phonegap media API for implementation.