# Play HTML5 video locally

Tags: html5-video, javascript

I have created a presentation application with HTML, CSS and JavaScript which is going to be executed from a CD. Everything is fine with images and JavaScript but now I want to include a video. I have tried www.videojs.com and it is working fine in Chrome, but I can't get it working with Firefox.

How can I include a video inside a HTML page that can be played locally, without any web server involved? The browser is going to be Firefox portable only.

Comment: I have even add some bounty to the question like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326008/how-to-play-embedded-video-in-wp7-phonegap and also interested in solution

Comment: What are you actually doing? Can't you just point a VIDEO tag at a relative file path?

Comment: what do the response headers say in firebug? this might be a problem with the partial content header

Comment: It worked for me after a while and honestly telling, i dont know what worked. I tried some more web video formats and putting the video at the same place as that of HTML page and it worked.